# Insert multiple column with where clause

Tags: sql-server

While inserting multiple columns of data with where condition, I get an error

```
insert into s_grpeffect(grpeffect_cess, grpeffect_rcm, grpeffect_fulllife)
values ('12.0000', '12.0000', '2019') 
where grpeffect_grpkid = 124;
```

Comment: This makes no sense ...INSERT is to create new rows. Therefore you can't use a WHERE clause because you aren't trying to restrict the query to any specific existing rows. If you want to alter existing rows then use UPDATE. This is quite a basic concept of SQL, so if you're unsure about it I would suggest maybe doing a little more study of the common types of query

Comment: `INSERT` doesn't supprt an `WHERE` clause - as a quick peek at the [MS official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) would have **easily** told you.....

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add where clause for insert statement.

```
insert into s_grpeffect(grpeffect_cess,grpeffect_rcm,grpeffect_fulllife) values('12.0000','12.0000','2019')
```

Or  If you are selecting value from table then below is the syntax,

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```